# How is it possible to keep a nice structure of scripts, contents, css, less, etc. in a larger web project while using NuGet?

Tags: visual-studio, web, nuget

I have a larger web project, using quite a lot of Nuget packages, mostly scripts and css (jQuery, bootstrap, 8-10 plugins, etc.).

I searched through the internet and unfortunately found that NuGet doesn't currently support configuring where to put these files inside the project. The result is a complete mess: mixed conventions, completely messy structure.

I thought I would solve it with a dirty, but working way: I would like Nuget to install packages, but NOT to copy and add content files to my project. I would like to manage them manually, so that copying those files from the `packages` folder to the projects where I want. Still I would be able to restore or update packages (and do a manual copy/overwrite again of course).

Is there any way to achieve this goal? Or if not, could anyone suggest me how these issues could be resolved, and how would it be possible to keep a nicely structured project while still using Nuget?

Comment: Have you tried adding the packages to an empty (or as close to empty that works) project (in a separate solution) and then manually copying the pieces you want? Keep the "package management" solution so you can see the impact of package updates.

Comment: @Richard that's an interesting idea, I will keep it in mind, and try it if there's no better way, thanks.

Comment: @Richard as a temporary solution I applied your tip and created a dummy, technical project called "_WebPackages" (in the already existing "Solution items" folder for not mixing with real projects), and added all of the NuGet packages there. I removed the packages from the real project, cleaned up everything, created my structure and grabbed everything  manually from the dummy project. It works fine, and totally worth the little manual overhead. If you add your comment as a complete answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the packages to an empty (or as close to empty that works) project (in a separate solution) and then manually copying the pieces you want?

Then keep the "package management" solution so you can see the impact of package updates.